# Which airports have jobs I can do for free?

Tags: microsoft-flight

In *Microsoft Flight*, most of the job postings at airports seem to be cargo or passenger missions which require the [Maule M-7-260C](http://store.steampowered.com/app/203872/).  What jobs can I do for free—with either the Icon or the Stearman—and where are they?

Answer (score 2):

You can only do the $100 Hamburger and Sightseeing jobs.  I am unsure if the airports always offer the same jobs or if they are randomly generated.

- $100 Hamburger

  - **Most airports** near Waimea-Kohala (the only that didn't seem to have it was Pahala Airstrip and Kaalaiki way in the south, and Kona Int'l)
  - ***Note***: These can only be done during the day.  To adjust the time, go to Free Flight (on the left), then Flight Conditions.  Adjust accordingly.
- Hawaii Biplane Tour

  - A few of the larger airports including:

    - Kona Int'l
    - Waimea-Kohala, and
    - Hilo Int'l.
  - *You can't do these at night*, adjust time as above.